# Stay in Datagrid edit mode when data is not valid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to wpf. With Windows Forms and a DataGridView I can force a user to stay in edit mode if the value entered in the grid is not valid (for example when entering letters in a column with ValueType set to double) with a code like this:

```
        DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
        grid.DataError += (sender, e) => { };
```

I'm trying to have similar behavior with the wpf DataGrid with no luck.
I tried the following binding options:

```
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "aHeader", Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("aProperty") { ValidatesOnDataErrors = false, ValidatesOnExceptions = false } });
```

But I can't see any change at all. Entering a non valid data causes the app to crash.
Any idea please?

Comment: 1 - Post the relevant XAML. 2 - forget winforms. WPF does not care about that, nor does it care about what you think you know from that. 3 - you need to use WPF validation.

Comment: 1- The DataGrid is built in the code not in xaml 2- ok, not very helful 3- How do I do that please?

Comment: do not create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. google WPF Validations.

Comment: In my case, the data and its type is known at runtime only. The grid is built depending on many variables that are unknown when coding. Anyway, how would you achieve the requested behavior in xaml?